# Coq: `Function ... with` syntax

Tags: function, syntax, definition, coq

It seems that, as w/ `Inductive` and `Fixpoint`, you can mutually define `Function`'s w/ `with`. Can you give the syntax and/or an example of this? I couldn't find anything anywhere. I suppose it's the same as for `Fixpoint`
(found nothing on this either). A non-working (but half-compiling -- the 2 last lines highlight in red) example:

```
Variable ARG:Type.
Variable phy inf phyinf: ARG.
Function Phy (x:ARG): ARG := match x with Inf x => phyinf | _ => phy end
with Inf (x:ARG): ARG := match x with Phy x => phyinf | _ => inf end. (*Error: Unknown constructor: Inf.*)
```

Comment: To me it's completely unclear what you're asking. Also: how can you say that your example is compiling if lines are highlighted in red. It precisely means the opposite! Finally, don't use "w/" or such kind of abbreviations.

Comment: You have a valid point: I corrected to "half-compiling". The compiler has several passes. If a line highlights in red, some of them were successful. Try removing one `end` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I finally understood your question.

There is indeed a way to mutually define several `Fixpoint`. It is (lightly) documented in the variant section [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmd.fixpoint).

Similarly, there is a way to mutually define several `Inductive` types (documented [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#mutually-defined-inductive-types)).

And there is a way to mutually define several [`Function`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-extensions.html#coq:cmd.function). Note however the remark that the manual makes about this feature:

> The `Function` construction enjoys also the `with` extension to define mutually recursive definitions. However, this feature does not work for non structural recursive functions.

The error that you are getting in your half-working example is not about syntax though, neither is it related to the `Function ... with` feature. The error is that you can only use pattern-matching on inductive types and branches must start with a constructor. In your example, `ARG` is not an inductive type and `Inf` is not a constructor. I can't really "correct" your example as I don't really see what you were trying to express. Was this example made just for this question? In this case, you stripped it down to too little.

PS: I wonder if somehow, you were trying to do [induction-recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction-recursion) (definining at the same time a recursive function and an inductive type). If this were the case, then no luck: Coq does not have this feature yet.

Comment: I must think what to do w/ this question. There are many problems w/ it, some of which I solved (w/ interesting results (an `Anomaly`, no less)) but...